# Generically relabel fixed-effect in coefplot

Tags: stata

I have ran a regression of type

```
reg foo I.year
```

and would like to plot the yearly effects. The regression result table looks like this:

```
  foo |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        year |
       2001  |   .1253994   .0047826    26.22   0.000     .1160255    .1347734
       2002  |     .06168   .0045566    13.54   0.000      .052749    .0706109
       2003  |   .1324228    .005008    26.44   0.000      .122607    .1422385
       2004  |   .1177605   .0051766    22.75   0.000     .1076143    .1279066
       2005  |   .1007163    .005018    20.07   0.000      .090881    .1105516
       2006  |   .0792936   .0047979    16.53   0.000     .0698897    .0886974
```

Unfortunately, when I use `coefplot, vert`, it says on the x-axis `Survey year=2001`, `Survey year=2002` and so on which consumes a lot of space. I understand that `coeflabels` allows me to relabel coefficients, but do I have to do that for every single one of these? What if I had 30 years - is there a more generic version of relabeling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a weird solution but it did work for me.
Simply add any value label to your survey year variable and it should recognize the years as their values.

In case adding **any** value label does not work, you can create a loop to set a value label for each year as its own year.

```
levelsof year, local(years)
foreach lvl of local years {
    lab def year `lvl' "`lvl'", modify
}
lab val year year
```

Comment: So this is about actually changing the variable label before running the regression, and not about cosmetics with `coefplot`, right?

Comment: It did work for me both before and after the regression. Apparently the graph requires the variable and not the output.

Comment: The loop was rqeuried for me